# Change direction of messages in ESB

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I'm implementing a mechanism to perform a rollback when certain errors occured during processing.

Errors are handled just before the message will be sent back to the initiator, that means in the very last part of the outsequence.

Now suppose I want to perform a rollback at this point, therefore I should be able to invoke the inSequence of a sequence already available. The problem is I don't manage to reach this IN-part, but it always gets into OUT.

I already tried to set the following property, but to no success:

```
<property action="set" name="RESPONSE" scope="default" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally managed to get it working. This easy script did the trick:

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
    mc.setResponse(false);
]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke a mediation flow which is used inside the In Sequence, you may move that particular section to a separate sequence and then refer it inside the mediation flow. 
(

A more detailed explanation about your service integration scenario will be helpful in answering with details.

This webinar may help you.

http://wso2.org/library/webinars/2011/01/wso2-esb-answer-enterprise-service-integration

Comment: Hi Kasun, thanks for your answer.

This would indeed have been a good alternative, unfortunately I didn't think of it before.